# Bash: Copy logs to other file and remove copied log

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I am using linux and doing some bash scripting. I have a log file which is making logs of all the events/changes our in particular directory. I need to copy these logs to some other file so that I can work on it. But I cannot just use:

```
cp /mnt/abc.log /tmp/xyz.log
```

Because it will not delete the logs which are already copied from `abc.log` - I need to copy the logs and then delete the copied logs (not the file) so that next time I will get new logs.

Because If I will copy the logs the delete that file and again recreate the file then I will loss the events occurred in the mean time. I need some bash script for this.

Comment: you want to clear abc.log after copying?

Comment: Yes I want clear only copied logs only - I cannot clear entire log file because its always written by filesystem.

Comment: did you try `> /mnt/abc.log` ?

Comment: You can try to roll your own with `cp source dest`, then `>source` to empty it and possible  `kill -1` to the program writing to it. But as Mark already answered, these problems have already been solved before and there is rarely a reason to create your own version. (Well, bar place with a NotInvertedHereSyndrome)

Answer (score 3):

Just use logrotate, or any of the log-rotation software that's available on the Internet.  There's no sense rolling your own here.